# Workbook not taking in variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a few macros on Excel I have tried everything but I believe I'm missing something. I'm trying to create two Macros that do the following:

Macro 1 = Create a new workbook with the name specified and store the path for the created file

Macro 2 = populate the created workbook with the data in a text file.

So far Macro1 is working fine and the workbook is created it is even able to pass the path of the file into the second macro. The second Macro halts halfway through with the message

> Subscript out of range (Error 9)

displayed at

```
With Workbooks(nameOfFile)
```

Below are my Macros

```
Global nameOfFile As String

Sub createNewSheet()

Dim version As String

version = InputBox("What version is being tested?")
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
Filename:="C:\Users\Uk000827\Documents\RegimeProject\RTD_Regime " & version
nameOfFile = "C:\Users\Uk000827\Documents\RegimeProject\RTD_Regime " & version
End Sub

Sub addValueFromList()

Dim strFilename As String: strFilename = "C:\Users\Uk000827\Documents\RegimeProject\IntelArchive.txt"
Dim strTextLine As String
Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
Dim r As Integer

r = 1
Open strFilename For Input As #iFile

MsgBox nameOfFile 
With Workbooks(nameOfFile)
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, strTextLine
        Cells(r, 1) = strTextLine
        r = r + 1

    Loop
End With
Close #iFile

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you think the second procedure knows the value of `nameOfFile`?

Comment: `nameOfFile` requires to be the entire filename, including file extension.

Comment: I've changed it to
nameOfFile = "C:\Users\Uk000827\Documents\RegimeProject\RTD_Regime " & version & ".xlsx"

But the issue still persists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this adjustment to createNewSheet (createNewBook...?)

```
Sub createNewSheet()

    Dim version As String

    version = InputBox("What version is being tested?")

    Workbooks.Add
    with activeworkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\RegimeProject\RTD_Regime " & version, _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        nameOfFile = .name
    end with
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow that's so it's working now.
Thank you so much. What was wrong with my version?

Comment: You were passing along the full path and filename without extension. You may have needed the extension, maybe not but you didn't need the full path to an open workbook. Asking Excel what .Name is would be  like asking it what it expects a workbook to be identified by so you cannot really go wrong. BTW, there is also the .FullName property.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a workbook by its full path. You just can do it via the filename (stripped of the path).

But there is a real problem with this code: If another workbook gets activated between the two macros being executed the second one just writes to that other workbook instead of the one named `nameOfFile`. That is because your `with`-Statement in fact doesnt do anything.

You may want to fill the cells using something like `.Sheets(1).Cells(r, 1) = strTextLine`. The `With`-Statement only refers to fields starting with a dot!

Comment: You are also correct, however, the problem was in the first Macro. Your way has allowed me to optimize my code and create a more stable Macro.